# When I try to open Nexus Mod Manager it gives me a message saying "Unrecognized Game Mode : Skyrim. How do I fix this?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

The title explains the problem. Getting message of "Unrecognized Game Mode : Skyrim" before opening up, after clicking on icon ( after giving the admin. ok).
Don't want to Uninstall because I don't know if it will still be on my Steam or computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the subfolders for your NMM install, you'll see there are dll's that match each game mode.   The error you are getting is usually caused by either a corrupt dll file, a permissions issue on reading the file (unlikely), or the file being missing altogether.

Your best bet is to uninstall NMM and reinstall it.